# asp.net core cliam based authorization throw "HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long." when large number of claim is set

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity, asp.net-authorization

I have implemented claim base authorization in my asp.net core 2.1 site. It is a ERP and has many section. Each section has permission like View,Add,Edit,Delete.
Suppose if I have 100 section , then it will be about 400 claims.

Role can have any or all claim. When a user having role that has all permission i.e 400 rows in [AspNetRoleClaims] table  for that role say "Administrator" role. When a user say "admin" has role "Administrator" try to login, he/she will get

**Bad Request - Request Too Long**

HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.

This is because cookie holding the authorization information exceed the length browser support.
[image]

[image]
About 281 rows and this will increase in near future when more module will be added.

Is there any way to solve this issue. Or any work around when I have to handle lot of permission. i.e each controller action could have different authorization policy.

Or if we can save these authorization information on Database or Session and not on cookie.

Is there any way to achieve lot of permission but not using that much of claim policy.

Can we force to check claim only when user browse particular controller/action instead of saving all permission information on cookie.

Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Are you storing entire OIDC tokens in your cookie? That might explain it

Comment: What do you mean by "claim base authorization" ?

Comment: "Each section has permission like View,Add,Edit,Delete. Suppose if I have 100 section , then it will be about 400 claims." - if you have fine-grained permissions then you should not be using strings. Use a packed format.

Comment: I wrote an alternative ticket format for ASP.NET Core when I was trying to shrink my own cookies down. It isn't suitable for secure applications (due to `CRIME`/`BREACH`) but you might find it useful: https://github.com/Jehoel/aspnetcore-auth-cookie-optimizations - it got my cookies down from 7KB to 2KB.

Comment: @Dai what you mean by packed format. Do you mean I should user integer instead of string for claim value.

Comment: " Do you mean I should user integer instead of string for claim value." - yes, but it's more complicated than that. Take a look at my example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using strings to store permissions - and you have a lot of fine-grained permissions. To make things worse, ASP.NET Core 2.x (by default) will store `String`-typed claims with [the full `WS-*` string type name](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/claims/ClaimValueTypes.cs,9f4523f9163bffd8,references) (`ClaimValueTypes.String == "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/#string"` which is awful... I don't know how that got past code-review, tbh).

First-off, if you always have exactly 4 boolean permission values for each item (`View`, `Add`, `Edit`, `Delete`), then you can pack that into exactly 2 bits, so you can store 4 areas per byte - so 400 areas will take 100 bytes (assuming you can identify them by sequential index - which is doable if you generate a mapping inside your application code).

As this involves custom ticket formats, you'll need to:

- Subclass `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.TicketSerializer`.
- Subclass `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>`
- Set-up the custom serializer in `IPostConfigureOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>`.

As I wrote in my comment, I wrote an alternative ticket format for ASP.NET Core when I was trying to shrink my own cookies down. [It isn't suitable for secure applications when GZip compression is enabled (due to `CRIME`/`BREACH`)](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10951) but you might find it useful as a starting-point for writing your own serializer: https://github.com/Jehoel/aspnetcore-auth-cookie-optimizations (it got my cookies down from 7KB to 2KB).

Comment: well-known and common Claim names and types are represented by a 1-byte integer instead of their full string representations. Do you mean it will only work on well known claim and not if claim name is not common.

Comment: Hi, Is there any way we can check permission on run time when we browse particular controller/action instead of saving permission  in cookie in advance.

Comment: @dilli.shrestha That's a completely different question to the one you're asking.

Comment: @dilli.shrestha If you are going to use my code then please read thoroughly: you can add your own claim-names and types to the code-book.

Comment: OptimizedTicketDataFormat.ChunkSize , doesnot contain a defination. Sorry, I am writing it here instead of your repo. Can you pls tell me, what is this, "ChunkSize" . It seems it is missing in "OptimizedTicketDataFormat" class

Comment: @dilli.shrestha Ah, I didn't document that - sorry. Yes, you can get that from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.ChunkingCookieManager.DefaultChunkSize` which is `4050`.

Comment: Appreciate you're response.  I made the exact mistake of using the whole url in the claim.  Good point with the CRUD operations too.  Customizing the cookie to be as small as possible then adding a middleware in the request pipeline to inflate the claims to something recognizable once the request hits the server works.  Thanks